# jetpack compose, UI subscribe to viewModel flow in launcedEffect:repeatOnLifeCycle can only collect One flow, and ignore the second

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

the 2nd collecting below does not collect until I remove the first one. also read from [Manuel Vivo] that there might be a limit of Only One Flow to collect somewhere in the stack. is this limitation true? did I miss something?

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        Log.d(TAG,"67 ")
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(state = Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            launch {
                viewModel.t2sRequired.collectLatest {
                    if (it) {
                        viewModel.t2sChar(context, 600)
                    }
                }
            }
        } //: repeastOnLifecycle
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(state = Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            launch {
                viewModel.snackBarVisual.collectLatest { visuals:SnackbarVisualsCustom? ->
                    if (visuals != null){
                        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(visuals)
                    }
                }
            }
        } // repeatOnLifecycle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limitation that would prevent multiple flows from being collected.

Your 2nd flow is not being collected because the block passed to the `LaunchedEffect` is a `suspend` function and is waiting on the 1st `lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle` which is also a `suspend` function call.

Check the left side bar in Android Studio IDE for the icon with an arrow with a green flow line, which shows you which calls are suspend function calls.
[image]

If you are collecting your flows on the same lifecycle event, then you can group both `launch` calls inside the same `repeatOnLifecycle` call.

```kotlin
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        Log.d(TAG,"67 ")
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(state = Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            launch {
                viewModel.t2sRequired.collectLatest {
                    if (it) {
                        viewModel.t2sChar(context, 600)
                    }
                }
            }
            launch {
                viewModel.snackBarVisual.collectLatest { visuals:SnackbarVisualsCustom? ->
                    if (visuals != null){
                        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(visuals)
                    }
                }
            }
        } // repeatOnLifecycle
    }
```

If you ever need to collect your flows on different lifecycle events, then you can use two `LauchedEffect` composables.

```kotlin
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(state = Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            launch {
                viewModel.t2sRequired.collectLatest {
                    if (it) {
                        viewModel.t2sChar(context, 600)
                    }
                }
            }
        } // repeatOnLifecycle
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(state = Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
            launch {
                viewModel.snackBarVisual.collectLatest { visuals:SnackbarVisualsCustom? ->
                    if (visuals != null){
                        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(visuals)
                    }
                }
            }
        } // repeatOnLifecycle
    }
```